# Java StringBuilder drop new lines between calls to append?

Tags: java, append, stringbuilder

Is it possible to configure the Java `StringBuilder` class to append a new line between each call to append?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `StringBuilder` has that functionality built-in. Since you can't just extend it, you could try using the decorator pattern...

```
class NewlineStringBuilder {

    private StringBuilder delegate;

    public NewlineStringBuilder() {
        delegate = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public NewlineStringBuilder appendLine(String str) {
        delegate.append(str).append("\n");
        return this;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return delegate.toString();
    }
}
```

Alternately Java can support this shorthand, which is useful in that it is not necessary for the decorator to reimplement all methods that need to be available from the decorated class, however it is more dangerous as the raw resource is completely unexposed so that trade-off must be weighed:

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
class AppendingStringBuilder {
    private final StringBuilder builder;
    AppendingStringBuilder(StringBuilder builder) {
        this.builder = builder;
    }
    public AppendingStringBuilder append(String str) {
        builder.append(str + "\n");
        return this;
    }
}
AppendingStringBuilder messageHelper;
// ...
```

Comment: Automatically - don't want to do this each time I call append.

Comment: I'm guessing there is some technical reason behind this, but could you explain what that is in your question?

Comment: The reason why you cant/dont want to just call `append("\n")`

Comment: It's duplicated code.  I take it as evident within the software development community why this is to be avoided.

Comment: Yeah, this I thought of.  I might use it if there's nothing more out-of-the-box (annoying the class is declared final).

Comment: Even if it wasn't final, you'd still have to declare references to your own custom StringBuilder class.

Comment: No, it's duplicated **data** -- You happen to want a newline after all of your strings. You don't need separate append calls, you just need `append(str + "\n");`